# Download with Volley gives error: Unexpected response code 200

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I am trying to download a file from my server. If I make this request through the browser I get the desired file, but when I use volley I first got com.android.volley.TimeoutError after I use setRetryPolicy I get

```
BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 200
```

Here is my class that makes the download:

```
public class DefexConnection implements Response.Listener<byte[]>, Response.ErrorListener {
private Context ctx;
private DefexDownload download;
public DefexConnection(Context ctx){
    this.ctx = ctx;
}


public void download(String link, final HashMap<String, String> params){
    DefexDownload req = new DefexDownload(Request.Method.GET, link, DefexConnection.this, DefexConnection.this, params);
    req.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy( 500000, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this.ctx, new HurlStack(null, getSocketFactory()));
    queue.add(req);
}




private SSLSocketFactory getSocketFactory() {

    CertificateFactory cf = null;
    try {
        cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        InputStream caInput = ctx.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.comodoroca);
        Certificate ca;
        try {
            ca = cf.generateCertificate(caInput);
            Log.e("CERT", "ca=" + ((X509Certificate) ca).getSubjectDN());
        } finally {
            caInput.close();
        }


        String keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
        keyStore.load(null, null);
        keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", ca);


        String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
        TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
        tmf.init(keyStore);


        HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier = new HostnameVerifier() {
            @Override
            public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {

                Log.d("CipherUsed", session.getCipherSuite());
                return hostname.compareTo("www.defexsecurity.com")==0; 

            }
        };


        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(hostnameVerifier);
        SSLContext context = null;
        context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");

        context.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(context.getSocketFactory());

        SSLSocketFactory sf = context.getSocketFactory();


        return sf;

    } catch (CertificateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return  null;
}


@Override
public void onResponse(byte[] response) {
    HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    int count;
    if (response!=null) {
        String content = download.responseHeaders.get("Content-Disposition").toString();
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(content, "=");
        String[] arrTag = st.toArray();

        String filename = arrTag[1];
        filename = filename.replace(":", ".");
        Log.d("DEBUG::RESUME FILE NAME", filename);
        try{
            long lenghtOfFile = response.length;

            //covert reponse to input stream
            InputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(response);
            File path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File file = new File(path, filename);
            map.put("resume_path", file.toString());
            BufferedOutputStream output = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
            byte data[] = new byte[1024];

            long total = 0;

            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count;
                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }

            output.flush();

            output.close();
            input.close();
            Log.e("DEFEX","file saved to "+file.getAbsolutePath());
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
    Log.e("DEFEX", "UNABLE TO DOWNLOAD FILE. ERROR:: "+error.toString());
}
```

}

Here is my class DefexDownload (which extends Request):

```
class DefexDownload extends Request<byte[]>{

    private final Response.Listener<byte[]> mListener;
    private Map<String, String> mParams;
    public Map<String, String> responseHeaders ;


    DefexDownload(int post, String mUrl, Response.Listener<byte[]> listener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener, HashMap<String, String> params){
        super(post, mUrl, errorListener);
        setShouldCache(false);
        mListener = listener;
        mParams=params;
    }

    @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws com.android.volley.AuthFailureError {
        return mParams;
    }

    @Override
    protected void deliverResponse(byte[] response) {
        mListener.onResponse(response);
    }

    @Override
    protected Response<byte[]> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        //Initialise local responseHeaders map with response headers received
        responseHeaders = response.headers;

        //Pass the response data here
        return Response.success(response.data, HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
    }

}
```

I have no clue what could be wrong here, any help will be gratly appreciated

Edit: on every other answer I found here on SO the problems seems to be the proxy or device emulator, but I'm running my app on my real device which is not using any proxy

Comment: Are you sure that `SSLSocketFactory` created as expect, Please check LogCat for `getSocketFactory()` may be crash logged and return null,

Comment: getSocketFactory is working, there are other requests (common requests, not file downloads) that use this method and are working as expected, I removed them because I think they are not relevant

Comment: Are you testing using real device or emulator?

Comment: If you testing throw the emulator, try to stop you antivirus or firewall, and give it a trial, :)

Comment: I am testing on my real device

Comment: I could not do it with Volley, but I could succesfully download a file using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028306/download-a-file-with-android-and-showing-the-progress-in-a-progressdialog) (the solution that worked for me was solution 2 from the accepted answer)

Answer (score 0):

**According to this [issue](https://github.com/google/volley/issues/92) on Github.**

> So `HurlStack` is more or less just a thin wrapper around
>   [`HttpUrlConnection`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection). The `EOFException` is presumably coming from there
>   when trying to make the connection. I don't think there is much that
>   Volley can do about this, short of applying a safe workaround if
>   there's a known platform bug.
>
> The stack traces of the cause chain would be good to look at, since
>   the exception is being thrown by some platform class under the covers.
>   Otherwise, I suspect you would reproduce the same issue if you just
>   used `HttpUrlConnection` directly, which means there's unfortunately not
>   much Volley can do.
>
> Searching for the exception indicates a number of potential issues
>   such as
>   [Android HttpUrlConnection Url doesn't work on emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35990044/android-httpurlconnection-url-doesnt-work-on-emulator)
>   indicating networking issues on the machine in question which
>   explained why it was emulator only.

**Expectation of the issue:**

- Emulator connection is not well configured
- Host PC antivirus or firewall.

**Solutions**

- Try your code using real device.
- Try with emulator after configure network with host PC and stop antivirus ***or/and*** firewall.